# ExpandablelistView with API integration

Tags: android

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cp3a.png)[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEmCY.png)[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvsVB.png)In expandable list view expand and collapse event working fine.
And using Hash map i just display the parent layout as static.
I need to implement dynamic data for parent and child activities
So how to parse JSON data to the expandable list view?

Here is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final String URL_GET_DATA = "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/marvel/";
private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
private List<String> expandableListNumbers;

private HashMap<String,Contacto> listContactos;
private int lastExpandPosition=-1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if(lastExpandPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandPosition){
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandPosition);
                }
                lastExpandPosition =groupPosition;

        }
    });
}
private void init(){
    this.expandableListView= (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandLV);
    this.listContactos = getContactos();
    this.expandableListNumbers = new ArrayList<>(listContactos.keySet());
    this.expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this,expandableListNumbers,listContactos);

}
private HashMap<String ,Contacto> getContactos(){
    HashMap<String,Contacto> listaC = new HashMap<>();
    listaC.put("TEST",new Contacto("111-11-11","Text","Test",R.drawable.vendor_repair,1));
    listaC.put("Riya",new Contacto("222-22-2","Text","Test",R.drawable.vendor_repair_1,2));
    listaC.put("Juan",new Contacto("333-33-3","Text","Test",R.drawable.vendor_repair_2,4));

    return listaC;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use expandalble recylerview in place of expandable listview and follow these steps for json pasring it is very easy .

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/expandable-recyclerview-android/

Comment: I tried this tutorial.It is working.In this only expand and collapse actions are possible.But i need on second click collapse the parent activity which is expanded.

Comment: You should try this by yourself  need to study about recyclerview please do some research before asking the question.

Comment: I tried. And got expand collapse for expandablelistview. I need to integrate API using Volley library.Then How to implement this?